# MySQL: Query and join two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that I believe I want to JOIN. I'm very new to this and am not completely sure…

The first table is called **venues** with the variables *id, slug, name*, etc. The second table is **venue_terms** with the variables *id, option, venue, value*. The matching variables are obviously *venues.id* and venue_terms.venue.

What I want to do is query **venue_terms** for matching values and then `SELECT * FROM venues` that match.

I've been working with the following query, but haven't been able to get it to work. I know INTERSECT isn't the solution, but I'm nut sure which JOIN I should use.

```
SELECT venue
FROM venue_terms
WHERE `option` = '1' AND `value` = '10'

INTERSECT

SELECT venue
FROM venue_terms
WHERE `option` = '2' AND `value` = '4';
```

I want to match those venue_terms.venue to the **venues** table. Can someone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE: To clarify, I'm trying to search multiple option/value combinations that ultimately have the same venue.id's. Basically, I want to able to find all of the venues where (option = 1 and value = 4) AND (option = 2 and value = 10) AND etc… where all of these are true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to find `venues` that match conditions in **two** rows in table `venue_terms`. This can be accomplished by various methods. The most usual is by joining that table twice (another would be by a grouping query).

Here's the first way. Join twice to the `venue_terms` table:

```
SELECT v.id                                  --- whatever columns you need 
     , v.slug                                --- from the venues table
     , v.name
FROM venues AS v
  INNER JOIN venue_terms AS vt1
    ON  vt1.venue = v.id
  INNER JOIN venue_terms AS vt2
    ON  vt2.venue = v.id
WHERE ( vt1.option = 1 AND vt1.value = 10 )
  AND ( vt2.option = 2 AND vt2.value = 4 ) ;
```

If you have 3 conditions, join thrice. If you have 10 conditions, join 10 times. It would be good for the efficiency of the query to have a compound index on `(option, value, venue)` in the terms table.

Comment: I have UNIQUE index called `venue_term` for `venue_terms.option` and `venue_terms.venue` to prevent repeat INSERTs. I've just added an INDEX called `terms_group` with `(option, value, venue)`. How could I make this query more effecient using `terms_group`?

Comment: If you added the index, nothing more needs to be done. T|o check if a query will use an index (or what indexes it will use), try running `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`. The output is an explanation of the execution plan.

Comment: It will tell you what indexes will be considered and which will be used, what order the tables will be processed, etc.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. And that just means it will query the database faster?

Comment: You can add the `EXPLAIN` output in your question (or in a new question). You can also try the query with and without this index (and compare the 2 Explain plans). If you have big enough tables, you'll see the difference in speed.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM venue t1 JOIN venue_terms t2
ON t1.id = t2.venue
WHERE (t2.option = 1 AND t2.value = 10)
```

***NOTE: I believe option and value are of type `INT`.***

***If they are of type `varchar` then change above query to***

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM venue t1 JOIN venue_terms t2
ON t1.id = t2.venue
WHERE (t2.option = '1' AND t2.value = '10')
```

---

### Update 1

As per your new requirement, you will just need to add that condition with `OR` option as shown below.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM venue t1 JOIN venue_terms t2
ON t1.id = t2.venue
WHERE 
     (t2.option = 1 AND t2.value = 10)
     OR
     (t2.option = 3 AND t2.value = 14)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can add another WHERE statement? E.g. WHERE (t2.option = 1 AND t2.value = 10) AND (t2.option = 3 AND t2.value = 14), etc. I have multiple option/value's I'm trying to find the venues that match all of those variables. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT venue.*, venue_terms.*
FROM venue 
INNER JOIN venue_terms ON venue.id = venue_terms.venue 
WHERE venue_terms.option IN ( 1 ,2)
AND venue_terms.value IN (10,4)
GROUP BY venue.id
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken `ON venue.id = venue_terms` should be `ON venue.id = venue_terms.venue`

Comment: Thank you for this. This does successfuly return for just one option/value, But I need to match multiple option/values e.g. get venues where option=1,value=10 and option=4,value=12 is true, etc.

Comment: This does work, but returns repeat venues. So, if both match venue.id =2 they're returned twice. It does work, though, so I could just filter repeats. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This will join the two tables and print out the venues which matches the attributes (option, value) in venue_terms:

```
SELECT v.* FROM venue v, venue_terms vt
WHERE v.id = vt.venue
AND vt.option = 1 
AND vt.value = 10
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This does successfuly return for just one option/value, But I need to match multiple option/values e.g. get venues where option=1,value=10 and option=4,value=12 is true, etc.